# Minimal APNS item IDs requirements

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

On https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4 there are 5 item ID's.

Token and Payload are mandatory but what about the other three? (`Notification Identifier`, `Expiration Date`, `Priority`)

Are all of them necessary? Can they be out of order?

Comment: Why -1 ? Is this information actually available somewhere?

Comment: here are some payloads under "Examples of JSON Payloads" at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Comment: @turbo Thanks but I do already have my payload figured out and functioning. My issues stem from packing the payload along with the other item(s) (token, etc) for transmission to APNs. I had a working `SimpleNotification` but I am having trouble building the `EnhancedNotification`. In attempting to troubleshoot the issue, I find the documentation to be lacking with regard to what is minimally necessary. (I took out the payload keyword in the title as I think that was misleading)

Comment: then i think u need to provide all listed in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/LegacyFormat.html

Comment: Very useful link. I thought what I was looking at *was* the Enhanced Notification Format.

Comment: I've since gotten the `command = 2` notifications working